# read .doc file using scala

Tags: scala, doc, file-read

I want to read .doc file in scala. I tried using apache.poi library for this but the method HWPFDocument(java.io.InputStream istream) accepts java io stream.
If anyone can shed some light on this, that would great!

Answer (score 2):

So, here is a teaser to get you started:

```
val fis = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file/doc.doc")

val doc = new HWPFDocument(fis)

val we = new WordExtractor(doc)

val paras = we.getParagraphText()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InputStream` in Scala, just as any other Java class/interface.

Comment: I am new to scala. I thought scala have some alternative for InputStream.

Comment: Even when Scala does provide alternatives to classes/interfaces in standard Java libraries, they are just this: alternatives. You can still use the Java classes. And you have to when working with Java libraries which use them.